# How to setup environment with cut-in commentary?

Tags: environments, italic

In my text there need to be sdome parts thast are distinguished bt being:

- in shorter line length;
- smaller line intterval, for example 1 as opposed to 1.5 for main text$
- possibly, smaller text size;
- italic.

From what i checked, quotes fit for some of that, but they also add big spaces before and after, and also quotation marks. Also i did not manage to mak them into italic.

How can i do such a thing? Here is roughly how it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given much to work with (no document class, no explanation how you set the line spacing, ...) so there is a good amount of guesswork in what follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myquote}{%
   \vspace*{-.6\baselineskip}%
   \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
   \item\relax
   \itshape
   \small
   \singlespacing
  }{%
   \endlist
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[75]
\begin{myquote}
\lipsum[66]
\end{myquote}
\lipsum[75]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You even took the name from my MWE, `myquote` and still beat me by two minutes, LOL. +1 to you.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Life isn't fair sometimes `:-)`. In fact, I was unsatisfied with the `.6\baselineskip` but I decided to let it go. In my usual perfectionist mood it would have taken longer...